# OutOfMemory Exception for Where clause

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, out-of-memory

I am using entity Framework 6 with `LazyLoadEnabled = false` configuration nothing else.I am using UnitOfwork repository pattern in my project.
And I have around 1,50,000 records in a table with foreign key relations to around 5 tables. Now my requirement is I have to implement server side pagination.For that, first I am querying this table to get exact count after applying some basic filters(like isactive and created by user) like below :

```
public long Count(Func<TEntity,bool> where)
{
    return DbSet.Where(where).Count();
}
```

then I am applying some search string filter and include some foreign references like below :

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetWithInclude(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params string[] include)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.DbSet;
    query = include.Aggregate(query, (current, inc) => current.Include(inc));
    return query.Where(predicate);
}
```

but in both methods, I am getting `OutOfMemory exception` since I have used `Where` clause . Kindly help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really just to expand on the [answer from Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45547478/1663001). Because your `Count` method takes a `Func<TEntity,bool>`, you are forcing the compiler to choose [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the more specific [`Queryable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx). This forces your entire DbSet to be materialised into memory - all 1,500,000 rows. So change the method signature to take an `Expression` instead, and while you're there, you don't need to call `Where`, instead use the other overload of `Count`:

```
public long Count(Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>> where)
{
    return DbSet.Count(where);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should change your signature to include `Expression` to avoid the full load of the records into memory.

```
public long Count(Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>> where)
```

*Aside:* LINQ already has a `Count` operator that you can use.